# How to test if a string is a valid C++(ish) expression?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11, expression

I am writing a program in C++ that needs to be able to test if a string (probably `std::string`) is a valid C++ expression. Variables can be checked if they have been declared (`bool variableDeclared(std::string identifier)`) and their type can also be checked (`std::string variableType(std::string identifier)`). The `variableType` function returns a string based on how it would be declared in C++ (`"bool"`, `"double"`, `"char"`, etc).

The expression doesn't need to be evaluated but only tested to see if it is valid. The function only needs to support character literals, string literals, number literals, brackets, simple operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `!` (logic not), `&&`, `||`, `>`, `<`, `==`), and variables of type `double`, `std::string` (no function calls needed), `bool` and `char`. It is also not required to support string concatenation.

The desired result would be a function that is something like `bool validExpression(std::string expression)`. It is also preferable that it allows me to modify the operations (for example I could change `"=="` to `"equal-to"`).

How would I implement this? Is there a library that could do something like this, a regex statement or is it simply a matter of a long function with lots of `if` statements?

Comment: Compile it. If it compiles, then *maybe* it's valid code. What's the purpose of this exercise? Are you trying to write a scripting language? This can be a long, ugly road to go down, but it's also quite interesting. Remember compiling and executing arbitrary code is a very, very bad idea unless you have absolute trust in the people providing the code.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous you could try implementing a parser with a tool like [Ragel](http://www.colm.net/open-source/ragel/).

Comment: You need to construct Context Free Grammar [CFG] and then check if the given string can be generated by the [CFG].

Comment: @tadman The OP mentions support for brackets is needed, meaning the language is not regular.

Comment: As said, compile your strings as code. And I think the best way to compile it using LLVM API.

Comment: @Angew That's today's requirements, but these things have a way of evolving due to scope creep. Just planning ahead one step.

Comment: If you've never done anything like this before, I'd recommend writing a simple expression evaluator to get started. The allowed parts should be integers (e.g. `123`), parens (`(`, `)`), `+`, and `*`. Then `calc("1+2*3")` should return 7.

Comment: @tadman You do realise the problem is that the OP's problem is *harder* than what regular languages can sovle, right?

Comment: @Angew That's why I mentioned writing a parser using a tool like Ragel as one option, presuming one's prepared to break down their grammar in very specific detail.

Comment: @tadman First sentence on that page: "Ragel compiles executable finite state machines from regular languages." Which means it cannot do what the OP wants. Why recommend it, then?

Comment: @agnew Since you're advocating Bison you probably don't know what Ragel does. It's a combination parser/interpreter *if* you want it to be, but can just as easily produce token streams if that's all you care about. It's quite flexible and can do everything Bison can, typically with less mess. I've used it before and it works great for this sort of situation. It can be a compiler, an interpreter, or just a tokenizer depending on what code you write for it. As a plus it can emit C code if you want.

Comment: @tadman No, this is the first time I've heard of Ragel. But the first sentence of its description states that it cannot be used to generate a parser for languages which contain nestable parentheses. If you use it just as a tokeniser (cf. Flex) and build the parser yourself, fine. But tokenising the OP's input is *trivial.* It's parsing that needs some work.

Comment: @Angew The line between tokenizer and parser is a lot more blurred in Ragel than it is in other systems (Flex/Bison), so I'm not sure where your criticism is coming from. If you want it to be a parser you can *make* it a parser, you just layer in more code. If you want it to be a tokenizer, you don't have to do much work. If you haven't used it, it's worth trying, as it handles grammar definitions surprisingly well. I'm not sure where your concern about nested brackets comes from as Ragel has always supported that even if your interpretation of the description suggests otherwise.

Comment: @tadman It's not "my interpretation." A regular language (~ finite state machines) cannot handle nested brackets, a context-free language (~ stack machine) is required for that. See [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). If Ragel supports context-free grammars, it should definitely not advertise itself as a finite state machine/regex tool.

Comment: @Angew I'd suggest you try using it before passing judgement. It's a lot more flexible than that awkward description implies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally, your situation is: you have a grammar which describes the language of expressions which you want to validate, and a word for which you want to determine whether it belongs in that language. This is a job for a parser of that language.

You could hand-cook something like a recursive-descent LL(1) parser, or use a tool to generate a parser. A well-known example of such a tool is [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for generating LALR(1) parsers. Wikipedia has a long [parser generator list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

---

Technical terms are used above mainly to provide entry points for googling.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to write this by hand is as a set of mutually recursive functions (look up recursive descent).

Comment: @melpomene: the easiest way to write this is with bison, as this answer suggests. It's not going to be more than a few lines of grammar, particularly if you don't need to distinguish between operators. Add a dozen lines of flex to build the lexer, and you're done.

Comment: @rici OK, but bison is not "by hand", which is what my comment was about. And I disagree that it's the easiest way in general: If you've never written a parser before, learning two entirely new tools (bison, flex) just for a simple syntax checker can be a very high barrier.

Answer (score 1):

You would start from defining your language more or less formally. (A language is a set of strings). A good way to define a language is to specify its context-free grammar. Describe additional conditions (like the requirement that variables must be declared, and of the right type) informally in prose.

The next step would be building a parser for your grammar specified at the previous step. There are several tools for building parsers from grammars automatically, from yacc/bison to boost::spirit.

After building and checking the parser, implement the informally-specified rules and plug them into your parser code/data.

Normally the next step, building an evaluator, would probably the easiest part of writing a simple interpreter, but you say you don't need one.

Describing your language as "just like C++ only with certain bits taken out" could be a preliminary step to the sequence outlined above. It is however not recommended to start out from C++ if you can help it. C++ is an extremely hard language to specify formally, and its parsers tend to be rather hairy, due to its convoluted declaration syntax.

Answer (score -3):

you can run compiler as sub-process of your application. All you have to do is to pass arguments and parse response properly

Comment: This 1) is quite heavyweight, 2) requires installing a compiler along with the OP's program, and 3) would accept things the OP doesn't want (functions, conditional operators etc.)

Comment: And it wouldn't allow things the OP wants (e.g. changing `==` to `equal-to`).

Comment: @Angew, you can run compiler with syntax check only flag

Comment: @melpomene, you can add defines as compiler arguments

Comment: Macro names must be valid identifiers. `==` and `equal-to` are not and cannot be redefined.